# Maximo Anywhere Transition To new view issue

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am working on Maximo Anywhere (7.5.2) - Work Execution app. I need to pass the view id in runtime to the "transitionTo" command.

Ex:
In app.xml, I can see few values are mentioned as {0} or {1}. How it works ? can the same way, I can pass the view id to tranisitionTo={1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{0} or {1} are array values you dynamically set using resolverFunction.
Below ex would help you understand better.In app.xml i have below code

```
<view id="WorkExecution.FailureListLookupView" label="Select {0}" resolverClass="application.handlers.FailureCodeHandler" resolverFunction="resolveNextFailureType">

resolveNextFailureType : function(eventContext) {
        var failureListSet = eventContext.application.getResource('failureListResource');
        var type;

        if (failureListSet.data[0].type){
            type = failureListSet.data[0].type;
        } else {
            type = this._failureClassMessage();
        }   
        return [type];

    },
```

[type] is {0} in app.xml